# AnyLogic error "Invalid Project File Format"

Tags: anylogic

When trying to open my model, I'm getting the error message "Invalid Project File Format" the file format is .alp. I don't think this is the reason, I saw here (https://www.researchgate.net/post/Anylogic_problem_of_alp_extension_it_says_invalid_file_format) that the reason is copying and pasting a parameter, and yes I did that I copied a parameter in the main and pasted then changed its name.
This problem can be solved, or should I not try?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this error before. When I brought it up with AnyLogic support, this is the advice I received:

> The error indicates that the model was corrupted. If you open the .alp
> file in any text editor, you can see that some part of content is
> missing.

There might be a backup file in the folder with the model. It is named like <model_name>.alp.bak. You need to remove ".bak" characters from the file name to recover the model.

*Note that .bak files are hidden by default.* Follow these steps to see a .bak file in the model folder:

1. Open Folder Options by clicking the Start button > Control Panel > Appearance and Personalization, and then clicking Folder Options.
2. Click the View tab.
3. Under Advanced settings, click Show hidden files and folders, and then click OK.

Comment: Unfortunately there is now backup files. I found the backup file for other models but not for the model that have the problem.

Comment: might be a small fix you need to do in the broken file (like a missing `}`). But may also be massive, hard to tell